# Is this code Implementation defined?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int i=257;
  int *ptr=&i;

  printf("%d%d",*((char*)ptr),*((char*)ptr+1));
  return 0;
}
```

Will the output of the above code implementation defined and the output will vary between little endian and big endian machine?

Comment: `printf("%d%d",((char*)ptr)[0],((char*)ptr)[1]);` is more readable imho. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be implementation defined behaviour.

When you cast `ptr` with `(char *)` and then access the first memory location, the first byte stored in memory will be accessed, which will depend on if system is a big-endian or a little-endian system.

Before calling the `printf` function the arguments are evaluated. And this evaluation as said above will get different values for different systems. Therefore it is implementation defined.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. The classic way to detect endianness at run time is the following way:

```
uint32_t var = 1;
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t*)&var;

if(*ptr) puts("Little Endian");
else puts("Big Endian");
```

Even though 257 => 0x0101, an int is most likely 32 bits in which case on a BE machine it will print 00 and on LE, 11.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will.
I always write it this way since I am never sure about operator precedence:

```
*(((char*)ptr)+1)
```

And to achieve what you want change your `%d` to a `%c` in the format string.

Comment: @tristopia: I find array indexing on variables that *are* not arrays to be *less* readable. Just to prove that opinions differ on this point.

Comment: Memory *is* an array of chars. Especially for pointer on chars is the [] notation always more readable imo.